# How could i make an array of removed tiles?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So i have a procedural generated game that loads in chunks, i need a  way for my code to remember if i cut down a tree or broke a rock so it doesnt replace it when leaving and entering a new area. I got it almost working except instead of putting them back in the correct place, it moves them to fill in the blanks. (if that makes since)

this is the slimmed down function of what adds the removed tiles to my array of removed tiles

```
    public function removeAndAddTile(tileRemoved:Function, tileAdded:Function, i:int)
    {

        world.removedTiles.push(world.tilesInWorld[i]);

    }
```

This is what loads after the tiles get placed when entering an area. In other words, whats suppose to be replacing the tiles that have already been destroyed

```
    protected function usedTiles()
    {
        for (var i:int = world.tilesInWorld.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            for (var c:int = world.removedTiles.length - 1; c >= 0; --c)
            {
                if (world.tilesInWorld[i].x == world.removedTiles[c].x && world.tilesInWorld[i].y == world.removedTiles[c].y)
                {
                    var ti:String = world.tilesInWorld[i].onTile;
                    var tx:int = world.removedTiles[c].x;
                    var ty:int = world.removedTiles[c].y;
                    world.worldTiles.removeChild(world.tilesInWorld[i]);
                    switch (ti)
                    {
                        case "grass" :
                            world.tilePool.returnSprite(world.tilesInWorld[i]);
                            break;
                        case "stone" :
                            world.rockPool.returnSprite(world.tilesInWorld[i]);
                            break;
                    }
                    world.tilesInWorld.splice(i, 1);
                    clicked = true;
                    switch (ti)
                    {
                        case "grass" :
                            world.tile = world.tilePool.getSprite();
                            break;
                        case "stone" :
                            world.tile = world.stonePool.getSprite();
                            break;
                    }
                    world.tile.width = world.TILE_SIZE;
                    world.tile.height = world.TILE_SIZE;
                    world.tile.x = tx;
                    world.tile.y = ty;
                    world.tilesInWorld.push(world.tile);
                    world.worldTiles.addChildAt(world.tile, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question simply is, how can i get my tiles to remember when they have been destroyed and to delete and replace those tiles when entering an area?

http://www.fastswf.com/PJyyXsc

Answer (score 1):

You could use two layers. One bottom layer for the map surface, and another detail layer contains trees, rocks. When your role moves and new area tiles appear, try to get the new area tiles data and add the trees, rocks to the new tile positions.

```
//the key may be tileX_tileY, the value will be the object type
//if a rock or a tree been broke,delete detailDic[tileX_tileY]
var detailDic:Dictionary;
```

When your role moves and enter a new area

```
var newTiles:Array;//the new appeared tiles

for each (var tile:Tile in newTiles)
{
    var key:String = tile.tileX + "_" + tile.tileY;

    var objectType:String = detailDic[key];

    if (check ojectType is valid)
    {
       add the wanted tree, rock to target position.
    }
}

//here you should remove the trees and rocks that disappear from your map's ViewPort
```

Comment: hmmm ill try something like this and will let you know how it goes. Seems reasonable tho